# Ruby C API `defined? SomeConstant` equivalent?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I'm trying to convert an if condition of:

```
unless defined? SomeConstant
  # do some stuff
end
```

Into part of a native C extension.  Does anybody know how to do the `defined?` predicate check in the C API?

EDIT | I guess I could invoke:

```
rb_funcall(rb_cObject, rb_intern("const_defined?"), 1, rb_intern("SomeConstant"))
```

Though this is obviously slightly different, semantically.

Comment: `Object.const_defined?` might be as good as you're going to get. The actual `defined?` keyword is implemented in `insns.def` (look for `DEFINE_INSN`) and that calls `vm_get_ev_const` which is static inside `vm_insnhelper.c` and thus inaccessible.

Comment: I think you're right, thanks!  Would you like to make that an answer? :)

Comment: I put down some notes but it isn't (of course) always as simple as `Object.const_defined?`. Of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trace through the 1.9.3 source, you'll find that `defined?` is implemented in [`insns.def`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/insns.def#L749):

```
DEFINE_INSN
defined
(rb_num_t op_type, VALUE obj, VALUE needstr)
/* ... */
    switch (type) {
    /* ... */
      case DEFINED_CONST:
        klass = v;
        if (vm_get_ev_const(th, GET_ISEQ(), klass, SYM2ID(obj), 1)) {
            expr_type = "constant";
        }
        break;
```

So when you `defined? SomeConstant`, you trickle through that big `switch` and end up calling `vm_get_ev_const`. The function is defined in [`vm_insnhelper.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/vm_insnhelper.c#L1160):

```
static inline VALUE
vm_get_ev_const(rb_thread_t *th, const rb_iseq_t *iseq,
                VALUE orig_klass, ID id, int is_defined)
```

That function happens to be static so you can't get at it. Looks like `vm_get_ev_const` is defined in terms of [`rb_const_defined`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/variable.c#L1846) and [`rb_const_defined_from`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/variable.c#L1858) and both of those should be available in your C so you could try those; but you'd have to find the right `klass` for those.

Or you could go with your idea and just use `Object.const_defined?`. One problem with that is that it won't do The Right Thing with things like `A::B`, you'd have to say `Object.const_defined? :A && A.const_defined? :B` for that as `Object.const_defined? :'A::B'` will just throw an exception in your face. A general solution here would require iteration and class lookups. However, if the classes that you're looking at are all in the top level namespace, then a simple `Object.const_defined?` should do the trick.

Comment: `rb_const_defined()` is the method to use. `if ( rb_const_defined( rb_cObject, rb_intern("MY_CONST") ) )`

Comment: @thomthom coudln't find `rb_const_defined` declared in `ruby.h` on 1.9.3 or 2.0.0.

Comment: @mezis If you follow the link in "mu is too short"'s answer (`rb_const_defined`) - then it takes you to where it is located in `variable.c`.

Comment: And it is declared in `intern.h`: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/include/ruby/intern.h#L872

Comment: This is a nice tool to search the Ruby source: http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/ident?i=rb_const_defined

Comment: @thomthom ah, thanks. And for the curious, it's declared in `intern.h`, not `ruby.h`. I suppose that makes it part of the internal API, although not the "public" one. Use with caution :)